# Remembering options in a select box array after submitting through php

Tags: php, arrays, select, element

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="box[]">
        <option value="1" <?php if ($_POST['box[0]'] == "1") echo "selected=\"selected\";"?>>1</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if ($_POST['box[0]'] == "2") echo "selected=\"selected\";"?>>2</option>
        <option value="3" <?php if ($_POST['box[0]'] == "3") echo "selected=\"selected\";"?>>3</option>
    </select>
    <p>
    <select name="box[]">
        <option value="1" <?php if ($_POST['box[1]'] == "1") echo "selected=\"selected\";"?>>1</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if ($_POST['box[1]'] == "2") echo "selected=\"selected\";"?>>2</option>
        <option value="3" <?php if ($_POST['box[1]'] == "3") echo "selected=\"selected\";"?>>3</option>
    </select>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When I use box names "box1" and "box2", it works without a problem. What am I doing wrong?

********** EDIT ****************

Thanks a lot for your comments, but I actually found the solution myself, even if it doesn't make much sense. Instead of using $_POST['box'][0] and [1] at the if statement, I simply used $box[0] and [1]. Even though it's posted, apparently php sees it as a normal array, and not as some kind of $_POST-array! Working code:

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="box[]">
        <option value="1" <?php if ($box[0] == "1") echo "selected='selected'";?>>1</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if ($box[0] == "2") echo "selected='selected'";?>>2</option>
        <option value="3" <?php if ($box[0] == "3") echo "selected='selected'";?>>3</option>
    </select>
    <p>
    <select name="box[]">
        <option value="1" <?php if ($box[1] == "1") echo "selected='selected'";?>>1</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if ($box[1] == "2") echo "selected='selected'";?>>2</option>
        <option value="3" <?php if ($box[1] == "3") echo "selected='selected'";?>>3</option>
    </select>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: If you only select the second box, it should go into $box[0], then your script should fail.

Comment: phant0m, I see what you mean. In this case with select elements that isn't a problem, since all box array elements will have a value, since one option will always be selected (1 by default).Though I did bump into the problem you mentioned with checkboxes using the same technique. Do you have an idea of a workaround?

Comment: If every option that you can select has a unique value, you can always  associate the correct field with the value, if it's selected or checked. You could also use different names on the `<select>` elements of course. I would just keep the effective value that has a semantic meaning to it, local to the server-side application.

Comment: You're making a big mistake using $box. That way you're relying on the register_globals setting, which has been turned OFF in PHP 4.2.0 and has been deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. Besides that, register_globals is far from secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your comments, but I actually found the solution myself, even if it doesn't make much sense. Instead of using $_POST['box'][0] and [1] at the if statement, I simply used $box[0] and [1]. Even though it's posted, apparently php sees it as a normal array, and not as some kind of $_POST-array! Working code:

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="box[]">
        <option value="1" <?php if ($box[0] == "1") echo "selected='selected'";?>>1</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if ($box[0] == "2") echo "selected='selected'";?>>2</option>
        <option value="3" <?php if ($box[0] == "3") echo "selected='selected'";?>>3</option>
    </select>
    <p>
    <select name="box[]">
        <option value="1" <?php if ($box[1] == "1") echo "selected='selected'";?>>1</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if ($box[1] == "2") echo "selected='selected'";?>>2</option>
        <option value="3" <?php if ($box[1] == "3") echo "selected='selected'";?>>3</option>
    </select>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `$_POST['box'][0]` and `$_POST['box'][1]` ;) Since they are posted as an array, you need to approach them as a array.

Comment: +1. I stared at the code for few minutes but did not find anything wrong.

Comment: I actually do already use $_POST['box'][0], but I found already that that wasn't the problem. I edited my question with the solution I found.

Answer (score 0):

Both, elements have same name. Thats the problem. 
`$_POST['box[0]']` , `$_POST['box[1]']` , contains the array of the two elements, not the value it self.

Comment: See, @Martijn Dwars's answer for the right approach, to your quest.

Comment: Actually I found that php sees the element array as a normal array, and not as a $_POST-array. I edited my question with the new, working code solution I found.

Comment: You better post it as a answer, and accept it afterwards. Including the answer in the question, is not really acceptable here.