# storing select box values into an array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have two select boxes and a link.i select one value from the first select box and another from the second select box and click on the link.the values have to get stored in an array each time without the previous value getting replaced.how can i do this without using multiple select box?

```
<select name="sq" id="sq" >
<option value=""></option>
</select>

<select name="as" id="as" >
<option value=""></option>
</select>
```

sorry forgot to mention..its in codeigniter

Comment: How do you mean stored? Each time they change while on the page or each time after submit? Can you add some more of your code?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. You phrased your question in a way that is very hard to understand for me. Please try adding example input/output or examples to help us better understand your problem/goal.

Comment: Check and try  this sample way .[click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437763/remembering-options-in-a-select-box-array-after-submitting-through-php)

Comment: when i click on the link.the values selected have to get stored into an array.again i select two different values and click on the link.those values have to get appended with the other values.at the end i want to display all the values in that array.

Comment: So you probably want to post the select values with AJAX to your PHP and store them there?

Comment: @user2138679 Why did you tag PHP and AJAX? Would you like persistence? Would you like the links to selection to remain the same after you refresh the page or save on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would send the data with AJAX without page refresh:

Use for the link `<a href="#" id="submitlink">Submit data</a>`

Then add the following jQuery script: (you need to include jQuery library first)

```
$('#submitlink').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Stops default link behaviour on click         
    $.ajax({ 
      url: "yourphp.php", // where to send
      data: 'sq=' + $('#sq').val() + '&as=' + $('#as').val(), // select values
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data){
           // If you want to confirm
           alert('Added');
      }
   });
});
```

Then in your php script store the $_POST data in either a database or session...

Session example, storing:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if (!isset($_SESSION['sq']) $_SESSION['sq'] = array();
   $_SESSION['sq'][] = $_POST['sq'];

   if (!isset($_SESSION['as']) $_SESSION['as'] = array();
   $_SESSION['as'][] = $_POST['as'];

  ?>
```

To retrieve the results you could use:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if (isset($_SESSION['sq']) print_r($_SESSION['sq']);
   if (isset($_SESSION['as']) print_r($_SESSION['as']);
?>
```

But of course this could be elaborated.

Comment: i couldnt follow the session part..how do i send these values into my controller and display it over there widout session?

Comment: This is using PHP native sessions in the most basic way. You have told us nothing about controllers you are using. It's just a very basic script to add form data to a session cookie. I can't guess your setup, so please include relevant info about your PHP infrastructure and post as an edit in the original question. Still I think my solution is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use change event to store the selected values.

*Html*

```
<select name="sq" id="sq" >
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

*Javascript*

```
arrSelected = []
$("#sq").change(function(){
     arrSelected.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With the added info from the comments, here is my suggestion:

HTML:

```
<div class="selectLine">
<select name="sq[]" >
<option value=""></option>
</select>

<select name="as[]" >
<option value=""></option>
</select></div>
<a id="addOption">
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#addOption').click(function(){
    $('.selectLine').last().after($('.selectLine').outerHtml());
    $('.selectLine').last().prev().hide();
});
```

PHP receiving the post:

```
foreach($_POST['sq'] as $key=>$name){
    //Make sure you stay consistent with the keys to make sure the 2 values were entered at the same time.
    echo '<p>'.$name.' is a '.$_POST['as'][$key].'</p>';
}
```

Adding [] to the end of the name of inputs will place them in arrays. But you need more than one if you want more than one value...

You can remove `$('.selectLine').last().prev().hide();` to keep the lines displayed to the user so he can change the values if you want.

Comment: This is actually pretty interesting! I did not know html name attributes acted like this. Would you mind creating a fiddle demonstrating this?

Comment: That is hardly what the OP is asking for. Each select box is used only once on the page.

Comment: @jtheman it is still pretty close... A little tweak might be in order but the question is not that clear either.

Comment: @Salketer If the question isn't clear, isn't it customary to add a comment to ask for clarification?

Comment: No not close at all as the use for an array is within EACH select box, not between boxes. Also he is looking to store the values after each submit.

Comment: for example.i have two select boxes one for name and another for job.first i select name A and job Engr and click on the link or button.it gets stored in an array.again i select another name and job and it gets appended with it. after all my selection i have to display all the names and jobs i selected.

Comment: @user2138679 this should suit your need now

Comment: As the OP say he dont want multiple selects in one large form he wants to submit over again and store after each submit. See my AJAX example.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have persistence in your website, then I would recommend looking into [PHP Cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

In your case, you want to store an array, persistently, so you have a few options.

Either implement a [HTML Hidden Element](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlhidden.php) or you can use [Serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to store the array inside a cookie.